# How set float label for input?

Tags: html, css, forms

In HTML5 and CSS I want to have form with float labels.

I mean if the input is focused and valid the label goes top for 20px, but in empty condition the label be in top: 0px position. The problem is when the value is invalid it comes down to normal position. How can I get this, whereas when input is empty the top is 0 and when something is in input(valid or invalid) it goes up.

```css
.group label {
  color: #7B53C1;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
  top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: .2s ease all;
  -moz-transition: .2s ease all;
  -webkit-transition: .2s ease all;
}

.group input:focus ~ label,
.group input:valid ~ label {
  top: -20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #7B53C1;
}
```

```html
<div class="group col-md-12 no-padder form-group require-field">
  <input pattern="[0-9]+" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="price" name="price" type="text" required>
  <span class="highlight"></span>
  <span class="bar"></span>
  <label class="price">rial</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted? The question was a bit confusing

```css
     .group label {
     color: #7B53C1;
     font-size: 14px;
     font-weight: normal;

     float:right
     pointer-events: none;
     right: 25px;
     top: 0px;
     transition: 0.2s ease all;
    -moz-transition: 0.2s ease all;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease all;
    }
    .group input:focus ~ label, .group input:valid ~ label {
    top: -20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #7B53C1;
    float: left;
    width: auto;

    }
    
    
    
    
.group{
       width: auto;
      position: absolute;
   
   }
```

```html
<div class="group col-md-12 no-padder form-group require-field">
                <input pattern="[0-9]+" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="price" name="price" type="text" required>
                <span class="highlight"></span>
                <span class="bar"></span>
                <label class="price">rial</label>
              </div>
```

Comment: I´m confused aswell, I think he wants to change the label position, when the input is empty or filled. As far as I know there is no way to check if the input is empty with plain CSS. I suggest using JS --> check your conditions and add/remove a class to the label and let the class handle the position

Comment: Completely agree with you @MarcelSchmid

Comment: yes I want to change the position of label go to top when it is filled.

Comment: As said you need Javascript for this. you can check :valid in html5 but not if the inout has content or not you will need js for this

Answer (score 0):

you can use `input:valid + label`

without value

```
label { color: #333;}
```

if you add value ininput :hover or focus add what you want

```
input:focus + label, input:valid + label {
   color:red;
}
```

DEMO https://jsfiddle.net/8fhn6ux9/

Comment: this code is like mine but I want if it has pattern how to stay in new situation when the value is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

> I have referred [this site](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-make-floating-input-labels-with-html5-validation--cms-26120) to create floating input,

By using `keyup`, `focusout` and `focusout` you need to, set and remove `empty` class on floating label.

`empty` class has some styling for floating animation.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
label {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
label span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: -2em;
  font-size: .75em;
  cursor: text;
  color: dodgerblue;
  transition: all 150ms ease;
}

label.empty input {
  border-color: #d9d9d9;
}
label.empty span {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 1em;
  background: none;
  color: #cccccc;
}

input {
  border: 2px solid #f2f2f2;
  outline: none;
}
input:focus {
  border-color: #d9d9d9;
}
input:valid {
  border-color: #42d142;
}
input:invalid {
  border-color: #ff8e7a;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 150%;
}

form {
  margin: auto;
}

input, button {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  border: 2px solid #bdbdbd;
}

button {
  border-color: #616161;
  background: #616161;
  color: #f6f7f8;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form>
  <label>
    <span>First Name</span>
    <input type="text" pattern=".{3,}" required title="Enter at least 3 characters.">
  </label>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
<script>
$('input:empty, textarea:empty').closest('label').addClass('empty');

$('input').keyup(function () {
  if ($(this).val().trim() !== '') {
    $(this).closest('label').removeClass('empty');
  } else {
    $(this).closest('label').addClass('empty');
  }
});

    $("input").focusin(function(){
        $(this).closest('label').removeClass('empty');
  console.log('focusin');
    });
    $("input").focusout(function(){
   if ($(this).val().trim() !== '') {
  $(this).closest('label').removeClass('empty');
   } else {
  $(this).closest('label').addClass('empty');
   }
      console.log('focusout');
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you looking something like this:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 420px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 20px 2px #E1BEE7;
}
.wrapper h2 {
  padding: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 20px 0px #E1BEE7;
  color: #AA00FF;
  text-align: center;
}
.frm-wrap ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 0;
}
.frm-wrap ul li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.frm-wrap ul li + li {
  margin-top: 25px;
}
.frm-wrap ul li input {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #E1BEE7;
  color: #748590;
  padding: 18px 12px;
  background: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
}
.frm-wrap ul li input:focus + label,
.frm-wrap ul li input:valid + label {
  top: 2px;
  font-size: 13px;
}
.frm-wrap ul li label {
  color: #AA00FF;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 12px;
  top: 17px;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
.frm-wrap ul li button {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #7B1FA2;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h2>Login</h2>
  <div class="frm-wrap">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input type="text" required>
        <label>Username</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="password" required>
        <label>Password</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also check this Codepen https://codepen.io/kravisingh/pen/jYGeyY